# Flot x-axis tick labels misaligned

Tags: jquery, flot

I am using jquery.flot.js to plot a time-series graph. The axis tick labels are also drawn on the canvas (as opposed to using html). When viewing the graph on a small screen (such as an iPhone) the tick labels go out of alignment with the ticks.

[image]

X-axis options are as follows:

```
xaxis: {
    font: {size: 12, family: 'Arial'},
    labelAngle: -60,
    minTickSize: [4, 'hour'],
    mode: 'time',
    monthNames: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    tickFormatter: null,
    timeformat: '%d %b %H:%M',
    timezone: 'utc'
}
```

What do I need to do to get the tick labels properly aligned with the ticks?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me!

Comment: @Ryley, a bug in Flot?

Comment: Yes, sorry - that's what I meant!

Comment: Please create a fiddle.

Comment: What version of Flot, and what versions of any plugins, are you using?

Comment: @DNS, using version 0.8 alpha and the following plugins: axislabels, fillbetween, and time.

Comment: @DerekHenderson Could you update to 0.8.2?  A lot changed between earlier alphas and the final 0.8 release.

Comment: @DNS, I suspect management would balk at an upgrade.  I recall all sorts of things broke when I tried to upgrade to 0.8.1 a few months ago, and so they're reticent. Would I still be able to draw the tick labels on the canvas in 0.8.2, or would I be forced to use html? And is tick label rotation now supported?

Comment: Yes, you can still draw labels on canvas using the canvas plugin.  Tick label rotation has never been supported in the base version of Flot (it's coming in 0.9), so whatever plugin you're using to do that probably won't interact properly with the canvas plugin.  I'm really just suggesting that you give it a try with your example, so we can narrow down what's wrong.  It's tough to find a bug when you have a dev version that could fall anywhere within many months of very active development.